# I need to create a priority queue to insert characters frequency into it

Tags: c, priority-queue, huffman-code

In C language, I need help inserting the frequency of each character value in a file and insert them in a Priority Queue. The code I have currently, uses Sturct pair() to count the frequency of characters in a file. I need to add another struct called struct Qnode(), etc. Here is the code I have, but the priority Queue is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct pair //struct to store frequency and value 
{
    int frequency;
    char value;
};

struct Qnode
{
    struct pair nodeValue;
    struct Qnode *next;
    struct Qnode *front;
};

void popQueue(struct Qnode *front)
{
    struct Qnode *min = front;
    struct Qnode *cur = front;
    struct Qnode *prev = NULL;

    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        if((cur -> nodeValue).value < (min -> nodeValue).value)
            min = cur;
        
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (cur != front)
    {
        prev->next = min->next;
    }
    else
    {
        front = front ->next;
    }

    //return min; (gave error saying is must not return something)
}

void printQueue(struct Qnode *front)
{
    struct Qnode *cur = front;
    while (cur!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%c\n",cur->nodeValue.value);
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}

void pushQueue(struct Qnode *front, struct Qnode *newQnode)
{
    newQnode->next = front;
    front = newQnode;

}

struct Qnode *createQnode(struct pair Pairs)
{
    struct Qnode *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Qnode));
    (*p).next=NULL;
    p->nodeValue = Pairs;

    return p;
}



int isEmpty(struct Qnode** front)
{
    return (*front) == NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //command line takes in the file of text
{
    struct pair table[128]; //set to 128 because these are the main characters
    

    int fd; // file descriptor for opening file
    char buffer[1]; // buffer for reading through files bytes

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); // open a file in read mode
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++)//for loop to initialize the array of pair (struct)
    {
        table[j].value = j; // table with index j sets the struct char value to equal the index
        table[j].frequency = 0; // then the table will initialize the frequency to be 0
    }

    while((read(fd, buffer, 1)) > 0) // read each character and count frequency
    {
          int k = buffer[0]; //index k is equal to buffer[0] with integer mask becasue each letter has a ASCII number.
          table[k].frequency++; //using the struct pair table with index k to count the frequency of each character in text file
    }

    close(fd); // close the file

    for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) // use for loop to print frequency of characters
    {       
            if (table[i].frequency > 0)
                printf("%c: %d\n",table[i].value, table[i].frequency); // print characters and its frequency 
     }


   struct Qnode *fr = NULL;

   struct Qnode *np; // new pointer

   for (int i = 0; i < table[i].value; i++)
    {
      np = createQnode (table[i].frequency); //whater frequency
      pushQueue(fr,np);
    }

    while(!isEmpty(&np))
    {
        printf("%d \n", &np);
        popQueue(np);
    }
    
    return 0; //end of code
} 


Output: 
./frequency Genesis.txt
 : 38655
!: 2
': 264
(: 6
): 6
,: 3686
-: 47
.: 1312
0: 275
1: 1144
2: 1011
3: 774
4: 722
5: 346
6: 306
7: 307
8: 269
9: 293
:: 3738
;: 609
?: 149
A: 1624
B: 215
C: 112
D: 211
E: 301
F: 41
G: 312
H: 156
I: 691
J: 422
K: 25
L: 358
M: 114
N: 116
O: 204
P: 155
R: 273
S: 276
T: 251
U: 19
W: 94
Y: 14
Z: 47
a: 13854
b: 2449
c: 2494
d: 8990
e: 18982
f: 3578
g: 2004
h: 13104
i: 7647
j: 66
k: 914
l: 5112
m: 3885
n: 11115
o: 10038
p: 1693
q: 17
r: 7424
s: 8431
t: 13337
u: 3545
v: 1355
w: 2996
x: 68
y: 2678
z: 61
```

Comment: "not working" is never a good problem description. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: The point of a code forum like this is to post your task, what you think the problem is, how you've tried to solve it, and debug information. As the comment above stated, you haven't given anything helpful in figuring out your problem, or what the problem even is.

Comment: Are you being told to implement a Priority Queue, or do you think that's a solution?  Once you have the character frequencies, you could do a sort on the array so that they are in ascending/descending order.  Aside from a bunch of other potential bugs, when pushing to the queue, you are doing no evaluation of the order they need to be in, hence they are coming out in the same order as pushed.  What's the simplest thing you can do?

Comment: `popQueue` is not modifying the queue in the `cur == front` case.  `front` is local to the function, and modifying it has no effect.

Comment: `while((read(fd, buffer, 1)) > 0)` is going to be a *lot* less efficient than `while( (c = fgetc ...`. Buffering serves a purpose, and invoking `read` for every byte makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates that you don't the complexity of a Priority Queue to solve the problem.

If your problem is to implement a priority queue, then we can look at that.  See my comment on the original question as to where that might be going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pair //struct to store frequency and value 
{
    int frequency;
    char value;
};

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct pair *first = (struct pair *) a;
    struct pair *second = (struct pair *) b;
    if (first->frequency == second->frequency) return 0;
    // NB: Greater than comparison returning -1 results in descending order of frequency
    if (first->frequency > second->frequency) return -1;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //command line takes in the file of text
{
    // Use static data instead of file for demo purposes
    char const * data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    // Initialise the table
    struct pair table[128]; //set to 128 because these are the main characters
    for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++)//for loop to initialize the array of pair (struct)
    {
        table[j].value = j; // table with index j sets the struct char value to equal the index
        table[j].frequency = 0; // then the table will initialize the frequency to be 0
    }

    // Record frequency for each char in data
    for (const char *p = data ; *p ; p++) {
        table[(int)*p].frequency++;
    }

    // Sort the array
    qsort(table, sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]), sizeof(table[0]), compare);

    // Print out the results for any value in table with frequency > 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {       
        if (table[i].frequency > 0)
            printf("%c: %d\n",table[i].value, table[i].frequency); // print characters and its frequency 
    }

    return 0; //end of code
}
```