# I want to print on the frequency from a file that appears

Tags: c, priority-queue, huffman-code

In the ASCII table, there are 128 characters, but I only want to print the characters that appear in a file. EX: "j: 10" If the file is Count.txt and inside of it it has...

```
a
bb
ccc
dddd
eeeee
ffffff
ggggggg
hhhhhhhh
iiiiiiiii
jjjjjjjjjj
kkkkkkkkkkk
llllllllllll
mmmmmmmmmmmmm
nnnnnnnnnn
0000000000
111111111
22222222
3333333
444444
55555
6666
777
88
9
```

Then I only want it to print to the console the characters that are being used. not every character with " : 0".

Here is the output that I get...

```
Pushing Queue

: 23
: 0
~: 0
}: 0
|: 0
{: 0
z: 0
y: 0
x: 0
w: 0
v: 0
u: 0
t: 0
s: 0
r: 0
q: 0
p: 0
o: 0
n: 10
m: 13
l: 12
k: 11
j: 10
i: 9
h: 8
g: 7
f: 6
e: 5
d: 4
c: 3
b: 2
a: 1
`: 0
_: 0
^: 0
]: 0
\: 0
[: 0
Z: 0
Y: 0
X: 0
W: 0
V: 0
U: 0
T: 0
S: 0
R: 0
Q: 0
P: 0
O: 0
N: 0
M: 0
L: 0
K: 0
J: 0
I: 0
H: 0
G: 0
F: 0
E: 0
D: 0
C: 0
B: 0
A: 0
@: 0
?: 0
>: 0
=: 0
<: 0
;: 0
:: 0
9: 1
8: 2
7: 3
6: 4
5: 5
4: 6
3: 7
2: 8
1: 9
0: 10
/: 0
.: 0
-: 0
,: 0
+: 0
*: 0
): 0
(: 0
': 0
&: 0
%: 0
$: 0
#: 0
": 0
!: 0
 : 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 23

: 0

: 0
: 0
        : 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
```

And here is my code that I used, if someone could tell me what I would need to do to only print the characters in the file rather than the 0's.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct pair //struct to store frequency and value 
{
    int frequency;
    char value;
};

struct Qnode
{
    struct pair nodeValue;
    struct Qnode *next;
};

 void popQueue(struct Qnode **front)
{
    struct Qnode *pop = *front;

    *front = (*front) -> next;

    free(pop);
}

void pushQueue(struct Qnode **front, struct Qnode *newQnode)
{
    struct Qnode *n1 = *front;
    struct Qnode *n2 = newQnode;
    
    if (!(*front))
    {
        (*front) = newQnode;
    }
    else{

        if((*front)->nodeValue.frequency < newQnode->nodeValue.frequency)
        {
            n2->next = *front;
            *front = n2;
        }
        else
        {
            while(n1->next != NULL && (n1->nodeValue).frequency < (newQnode->nodeValue).frequency)
            {
                n1 = n1->next;
            }

            n2->next = n1->next;
            n1->next = n2;
        }
    }
    
    //newQnode->next = front;
   // front = newQnode;

}

struct Qnode *createQnode(struct pair Pairs)
{
    struct Qnode *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Qnode));

    p->next=NULL;
    p->nodeValue = Pairs;

    return p;
}

void printQueue(struct Qnode **front)
{
    struct Qnode *nodePtr = *front;
    while (nodePtr != NULL)
    {
       
        
        if((nodePtr->nodeValue).frequency > 0)
        {
            printf("%c: %d\n", (nodePtr->nodeValue).value,(nodePtr->nodeValue).frequency);
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        
    
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //command line takes in the file of text
{
    struct pair table[128]; //set to 128 because these are the main characters
    

    int fd; // file descriptor for opening file
    char buffer[1]; // buffer for reading through files bytes

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); // open a file in read mode
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++)//for loop to initialize the array of pair (struct)
    {
        table[j].value = j; // table with index j sets the struct char value to equal the index
        table[j].frequency = 0; // then the table will initialize the frequency to be 0
    }

    while((read(fd, buffer, 1)) > 0) // read each character and count frequency
    {
          int k = buffer[0]; //index k is equal to buffer[0] with integer mask becasue each letter has a ASCII number.
          table[k].frequency++; //using the struct pair table with index k to count the frequency of each character in text file
    }

   struct Qnode *pq = NULL;

    printf("Pushing Queue\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        struct Qnode *new = createQnode(table[i]);
        pushQueue(&pq, new);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
         
        printQueue(&pq);
        popQueue(&pq);
    }

    

    close(fd); // close the file

    
    
    return 0; //end of code
}
```

Comment: Please show also the output you _expect_, not only the output you get.

Comment: I want the output to only print the characters used, I tried in the printQueue function to use an if statement to wear if the value frequency is GREATER than 0, then only print that. but this doesn't work. Do I need a for loop?

Comment: Don't describe the output you want but show it. Same for your code.

Comment: this is what I want my output to be with file Count.txt. 0: 10
1: 9
2: 8
3: 7
4: 6
5: 5
6: 4
7: 3
8: 2
9: 1
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
d: 4
e: 5
f: 6
g: 7
h: 8
i: 9
j: 10
k: 11
l: 12
m: 13
n: 10 It doesn't print the characters that aren't included in the file.

Comment: You must advance your pointer even if you do not print. Otherwise you will never return from `printQueue` if there is one element with `frequence==0`.

Comment: Your code and output do not match. The code you show should cause an endless loop. The output you show cannot be created using that code.

Comment: Why are you using `open/read` instead of `fopen/fread`?  The former will be grossly inefficient.

Comment: @Gerhardh I was trying to edit it, that is my fault ignore the if statement in print queue, that is what the output is. I added the if statement to try and see and it only printed one " : 23" and then nothing happened

Comment: @William Pursell because that is what my instructor taught us, and didn't teach us fopen, I guess she want us to struggle more. lol

Comment: That `if` you added is wrong. You must move the line `nodePtr = nodePtr->next;` after the `if` block

Comment: I would assume you are not expected to print numbers for `\n`  etc..

Comment: @chefwink Learning `open/read` first is not a terrible approach.  It may make it easier to understand the benefits if `fopen/fread` when you do get to that.  It's probably not intended to cause extra difficulty.

Comment: Seems to be popular today - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086001/i-need-to-create-a-priority-queue-to-insert-characters-frequency-into-it

Comment: @WilliamPursell Seems they got given an outline of some code and told to implement the priqueue functionality.  "Ours is not to reason why, ours is but to do or die".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help.  You have some errors with pointers and functions which I tried to help with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct pair { //struct to store frequency and value 
    int frequency;
    char value;
};

struct Qnode {
    struct pair nodeValue;
    struct Qnode *next;
};

/*
void popQueue(struct Qnode *front) {
    struct Qnode *min = front;
    struct Qnode *cur = front;
    struct Qnode *prev = NULL;

    while (cur != NULL) {
      if((cur -> nodeValue).value < (min -> nodeValue).value)
        min = cur;

      prev = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
    }

    if (cur != front) {
        prev->next = min->next;
    } else {
        front = front ->next;
    }

    //return min; (gave error saying is must not return something)
}
*/

// Lets create dump routine
void dump_node(struct Qnode *pNode) {
  printf("dump_node(%p) BEGIN\n", pNode);
  printf("next %p \n", pNode->next);
  printf("pair.value %c \n", pNode->nodeValue.value);
  printf("pair.frequency %d \n", pNode->nodeValue.frequency);
  printf("dump_node(%p) END\n", pNode);
}


void printQueue(struct Qnode *front) {
    struct Qnode *cur = front;
    while (cur!= NULL) {
        printf("%c\n",cur->nodeValue.value);
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}

// Tweaked this one a bit
struct Qnode * pushQueue(struct Qnode *front, struct Qnode *newQnode) {
    newQnode->next = front;
    front = newQnode;
    return front;
}

struct Qnode *createQnode(struct pair Pairs) {
    struct Qnode *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Qnode));
    // Also lets simply the syntax, rather than
    // (*p).next=NULL;
    // lets do this:
    p->next=NULL;
    // This what you did here. I wonder why you used 
    // the different syntax presviously.
    p->nodeValue = Pairs;

    return p;
}



int isEmpty(struct Qnode** front) {
    return (*front) == NULL;
}

//command line takes in the file of text
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    //set to 128 because these are the main characters
    // To be more precise, there are 128 possible
    // ascii characters. [A-Za-z0-9~-_+=...] plus all the 
    // control/whitespace chars
    struct pair table[128]; 

    int fd; // file descriptor for opening file
    char buffer[1]; // buffer for reading through files bytes

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); // open a file in read mode

    //for loop to initialize the array of pair (struct)
    for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
      table[j].value = j; // table with index j sets the struct char value to equal the index
      table[j].frequency = 0; // then the table will initialize the frequency to be 0
    }



    // read each character and count frequency
    while((read(fd, buffer, 1)) > 0) {
      int k = buffer[0]; //index k is equal to buffer[0] with integer mask becasue each letter has a ASCII number.
      table[k].frequency++; //using the struct pair table with index k to count the frequency of each character in text file
      table[k].value = k; // JD edit. Add letter to value pair
    }

    // Print a few sample table entries 
    //printf("Should be three capital T's table['T'] = %d\n", table['T']);
    //printf("Should be nine lowercase i's table['i'] = %d\n", table['i']);
    // Hmm. its not so simple since the letter itself is not an index.
    // What is also odd, is that the table[].value is never entered.    
    // See my above edit to add it.
    printf("Should be three capital T's: table['T'].frequency = %d\n", table['T'].frequency);
    printf("Should be T: in table['T'].value = %c\n", table['T'].value);
    printf("Should be nine lowercase i's table['i'].frequency = %d\n", table['i'].frequency);
    printf("Should be i: in table['i'].value = %c\n", table['i'].value);


    close(fd); // close the file

    // use for loop to print frequency of characters
    // This is good.  It shows space char has nine occurances
    for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
      if (table[i].frequency > 0) {
        // print characters and its frequency 
        printf("%c: %d\n",table[i].value, table[i].frequency); 
      }
    }


   struct Qnode *fr = NULL;

   struct Qnode *np; // new pointer

   // lets test your createQnode routine
   fr = createQnode (table['T']); 
   // lets test my dump_node routine
   //dump_node(fr);
   // lets test your pushQueue()
   printf("front is %p\n", fr);
   // Try another to see if the queue is
   // working
   np = createQnode (table['i']); 
   fr = pushQueue(fr, np);
   dump_node(fr);
   dump_node(fr->next);



   // free the allocation
   free(fr->next);
   fr->next= NULL;
   free(fr);
   fr = NULL;


   // Here you are getting off the rails.  You never
   // updated value before. It would be garbage.
   // Now I have set your value entry for each,
   // however that is not your loop constraint.
   // You want to loop for each entry in your table.
   // Some entries are non existant, so that will be
   // addressed in the loop body.
   // NO: for (int i = 0; i < table[i].value; i++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
      // Add check for you as you did in your print.
      // No need to add entry for a character which
      // did not appear in the input text file.
      if (table[i].frequency > 0) {
        // orig np = createQnode (table[i].frequency); //whater frequency
        np = createQnode (table[i]);
        // If the front has not been created yet, init 
        // it with the first one
        if (NULL == fr) {
          fr = np;
        } else {
          fr = pushQueue(fr,np);
        }
      }
   }

   // Lets test to see if the queue is correct before we test pop
   struct Qnode *p; 
   p = fr;
   while(NULL != p) {
     dump_node(p);
     p=p->next;
   }


   // This set of code is overy complicated
   // for a quick reply.  You should 
   // pass fr pointer rather than np
   // and you don't need to take address of it.
   while(!isEmpty(&np)) {
     printf("%d \n", &np);
     popQueue(np);
   }

    return 0; //end of code
}
```

Comment: what would I do to popQueue?

Comment: Well, I think you are wanting to use it to print the content of the queue and also remove values of the queue. At the end I iterated the queue to print the contents.

I suggest you write a routine to do one thing.  I also suggest you look at how I implemented your push queue so that it works.  Remember C is kind of geared for parameters as inputs and the return as an output.  You can use pointer manipulation to have input/output parameters, but when you are first learning strive for simplicity.  You can do it. I believe in you.  Take a look at my answer and we can talk further.

Comment: @chefwink btw in regards to this comment in your code.  `//return min; (gave error saying is must not return something)`  That was an error because your function statement has `void` as the return type.  It means the function does not return something.  Yet when you specify `return min`, you are saying it does.  Hence the conflict.  Look at the difference in how I wrote your pushqueue() routine and used it.  It shows I'm using the return value to get the modified input parameter rather than try to use an input/output parameter.